# System files deleted somehow

Tags: ev3

I think my son accidentally deleted all the system sound/image files, etc. I have tried loading the firmware but that does NOT restore the files. Is there not a way to just upload the system sound and image files to the brick? They are so easy to delete, you'd think there would be a way to put them back....

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, my friend, this is less of a LEGO problem, and more of an issue with the kind of basic tech EV3 runs on. It can't afford to have a backup, it needs to be compact. You'll have to put them back on file by file.